# Is there a Solana NFT API to get NFT metadata on Solana?

Tags: nft, metadata, api

Hi I'm new to the Solana ecosystem, and I don't know where I can start, any help is appreciated
Irwing Tello

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is using [QuickNode's Solana](https://www.quicknode.com/) NFT API.

Check the following JavaScript examples,

**[To get NFT data for a wallet address:](https://www.quicknode.com/docs/solana/qn_fetchNFTs)**

```
const axios = require("axios");
(() => {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  };
  const data = {
    jsonrpc: "2.0",
    id: 1,
    method: "qn_fetchNFTs",
    params: 
      {
        wallet: "ADDRESS_HERE",
        page: 1,
        perPage: 3,
      },
  };
  axios
    .post("QUICKNODE_SOLANA_RPC_HERE", data, config)
    .then(function (response) {
      // handle success
      console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      // handle error
      console.log(err);
    });
})();
```

**[To get NFT data for a Creator address](https://www.quicknode.com/docs/solana/qn_fetchNFTsByCreator)**

```
const axios = require("axios");
(() => {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  };
  const data = {
    jsonrpc: "2.0",
    id: 1,
    method: "qn_fetchNFTsByCreator",
    params: [
      {
        creator: "ADDRESS_HERE",
        page: 1,
        perPage: 3,
      },
    ],
  };
  axios
    .post("QUICKNODE_SOLANA_RPC_HERE", data, config)
    .then(function (response) {
      // handle success
      console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      // handle error
      console.log(err);
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 3):

The [Digital Assets Standard API](https://docs.helius.xyz/solana-rpc-nodes/digital-asset-standard-api) by [Helius](https://www.helius.dev/) is probably one of the easiest solutions at the moment. It also supports both regular and compressed nfts.

Here is the example usage for the [getAsset](https://docs.helius.xyz/solana-rpc-nodes/digital-asset-standard-api/get-asset) method to fetch the metadata for a single NFT.

```
const url = `https://rpc.helius.xyz/?api-key=<api_key>`

const getAsset = async () => {
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      jsonrpc: '2.0',
      id: 'my-id',
      method: 'getAsset',
      params: {
        id: 'F9Lw3ki3hJ7PF9HQXsBzoY8GyE6sPoEZZdXJBsTTD2rk' // mint address of the NFT
      },
    }),
  });
  const { result } = await response.json();
  console.log("Asset: ", result);
};
getAsset();
```

Which returns the following data:

```
Asset:  {
  "interface": "Custom",
  "id": "F9Lw3ki3hJ7PF9HQXsBzoY8GyE6sPoEZZdXJBsTTD2rk",
  "content": {
    "$schema": "https://schema.metaplex.com/nft1.0.json",
    "json_uri": "https://madlads.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/json/8420.json",
    "files": [
      {
        "uri": "https://madlads.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/images/8420.png",
        "cdn_uri": "https://cdn.helius.services/cdn-cgi/image//https://madlads.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/images/8420.png",
        "mime": "image/png"
      },
      {
        "uri": "https://arweave.net/qJ5B6fx5hEt4P7XbicbJQRyTcbyLaV-OQNA1KjzdqOQ/0.png",
        "cdn_uri": "https://cdn.helius.services/cdn-cgi/image//https://arweave.net/qJ5B6fx5hEt4P7XbicbJQRyTcbyLaV-OQNA1KjzdqOQ/0.png",
        "mime": "image/png"
      }
    ],
    "metadata": {
      "attributes": [
        {
          "value": "Male",
          "trait_type": "Gender"
        },
        {
          "value": "King",
          "trait_type": "Type"
        },
        {
          "value": "Royal",
          "trait_type": "Expression"
        },
        {
          "value": "Mad Crown",
          "trait_type": "Hat"
        },
        {
          "value": "Madness",
          "trait_type": "Eyes"
        },
        {
          "value": "Mad Armor",
          "trait_type": "Clothing"
        },
        {
          "value": "Royal Rug",
          "trait_type": "Background"
        }
      ],
      "description": "Fock it.",
      "name": "Mad Lads #8420",
      "symbol": "MAD"
    },
    "links": {
      "external_url": "https://madlads.com"
    }
  },
  "authorities": [
    {
      "address": "2RtGg6fsFiiF1EQzHqbd66AhW7R5bWeQGpTbv2UMkCdW",
      "scopes": [
        "full"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "compression": {
    "eligible": false,
    "compressed": false,
    "data_hash": "",
    "creator_hash": "",
    "asset_hash": "",
    "tree": "",
    "seq": 0,
    "leaf_id": 0
  },
  "grouping": [
    {
      "group_key": "collection",
      "group_value": "J1S9H3QjnRtBbbuD4HjPV6RpRhwuk4zKbxsnCHuTgh9w"
    }
  ],
  "royalty": {
    "royalty_model": "creators",
    "target": null,
    "percent": 0.042,
    "basis_points": 420,
    "primary_sale_happened": true,
    "locked": false
  },
  "creators": [
    {
      "address": "5XvhfmRjwXkGp3jHGmaKpqeerNYjkuZZBYLVQYdeVcRv",
      "share": 0,
      "verified": true
    },
    {
      "address": "2RtGg6fsFiiF1EQzHqbd66AhW7R5bWeQGpTbv2UMkCdW",
      "share": 100,
      "verified": true
    }
  ],
  "ownership": {
    "frozen": true,
    "delegated": true,
    "delegate": "H433aRZo3yjDJaWuDrwRt9dKnrgkpUVL3z1VXdFis7kG",
    "ownership_model": "single",
    "owner": "CbSKdjmeR8ursxzJHXqk6sQJjQUCCC1sof6NLtABoTC4"
  },
  "supply": null,
  "mutable": true
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the [Metaplex SDK](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/js)

```
import { Metaplex } from "@metaplex-foundation/js";
import { Connection, clusterApiUrl } from "@solana/web3.js";

const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("mainnet-beta"));
const metaplex = new Metaplex(connection);

const mintAddress = new PublicKey("ATe3DymKZadrUoqAMn7HSpraxE4gB88uo1L9zLGmzJeL");

const nft = await metaplex.nfts().findByMint({ mintAddress });
```

Answer (score 1):

there is multiple solana explorers which also show you the meta data.
For example:
https://explorer.solana.com/
https://solscan.io/
https://xray.helius.xyz/
and more. Just paste in the address of your NFT there.